# How can I loop through nested tables in Lua when the nested tables are mixed in with other data types?

Tags: lua, nested-loops, lua-table

I'm trying loop though a very large table in Lua that consists of mixed data types many nested tables.  I want to print the entire data table to the console, but I'm having trouble with nested loops. When I do a nested loop to print the next level deep Key Value pairs I get this error `bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got number)` because not all values are tables.

I've tried adding a `if type(value) == table then` before the nested loop but it never triggers, because `type(value)` returns `userdata` whether they are ints, strings or tables.
**EDIT: I was wrong, only tables are returned as type `userdata`**

My table looks something like this but hundreds of pairs and can be several nested tables. I have a great built in method `printall()` with the tool I'm using for this but it only works on the first nested table. I don't have any control over what this table looks like, I'm just playing with a game's data, any help is appreciated.

```
myTable = {
    key1 = { value1 = "string" },
    key2 = int,
    key3 = {             -- printall() will print all these two as key value pairs
        subKey1 = int, 
        subKey2 = int
    },
    key4 = {
        innerKey1 = { -- printall() returns something like : innerKey1 = <int32_t[]: 0x13e9dcb98>
            nestedValue1 = "string",
            nestedValue2 = "string"
        },
        innerKey2 = { -- printall() returns something like : innerKey2 = <vector<int32_t>[41]: 0x13e9dcbc8>
            nestedValue3 = int,
            nestedValue4 = int
        }
    },
    keyN = "string"
}
```

My loop

```
for key, value in pairs(myTable) do
    print(key)
    printall(value)
    for k,v in pairs(value) do
            print(k)
            printall(v)
        end
    end
    print("====")
end
```

ANSWER : Here is my final version of the function that fixed this, it's slightly modified from the answer Nifim gave to catch edge cases that were breaking it.

```
function printFullObjectTree(t, tabs)
    local nesting = ""
    for i = 0, tabs, 1 do
        nesting = nesting .. "\t"
    end
    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        if type(v) == "userdata" then     -- all tables in this object are the type `userdata` 
            print(nesting .. k .. " = {")
            printFullObjectTree(v, tabs + 1)
            print(nesting .. "}")
        elseif v == nil then
            print(nesting .. k .. " = nil")
        elseif type(v) == "boolean" then
            print(nesting .. k .. " = " .. string.format("%s", v))
        else
            print(nesting .. k .. " = " .. v)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type(value)` returns a string representing the type of value

More information on that Here:
   [lua-users.org/wiki/TypeIntrospection](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TypeIntrospection)

Additionally your example table has `int` as some of the values for some keys, as this would be nil those keys are essentially not part of the table for my below example i will change each instance of `int` to a number value.

It would also make sense to recurse if you hit a table rather than making a unknown number of nested loops.

here is an example of working `printAll`

```
myTable = {
    key1 = { value1 = "string" },
    key2 = 2,
    key3 = {             -- printall() will print all these two as key value pairs
        subKey1 = 1, 
        subKey2 = 2
    },
    key4 = {
        innerKey1 = { -- printall() returns something like : innerKey1 = <int32_t[]: 0x13e9dcb98>
            nestedValue1 = "string",
            nestedValue2 = "string"
        },
        innerKey2 = { -- printall() returns something like : innerKey2 = <vector<int32_t>[41]: 0x13e9dcbc8>
            nestedValue3 = 3,
            nestedValue4 = 4
        }
    },
    keyN = "string"
}

function printAll(t, tabs)
    local nesting = ""
    for i = 0, tabs, 1 do
        nesting = nesting .. "\t"
    end
    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        if type(v) == "table" then
            print(nesting .. k .. " = {")
            printAll(v, tabs + 1)
            print(nesting .. "}")
        else
            print(nesting .. k .. " = " .. v)
        end
    end
end

print("myTable = {")
printAll(myTable, 0)
print("}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had to make some modifications to handle edge cases but I got this to work nicely, I'll add the final version to my post since it's too long for this comment. I believe it's catching every value and table now.